# Simulating cross talk of quantum hardware

Tags: qiskit, simulation, ibm-quantum-devices

I am working on some experiments on the IBMQ Guadalupe machine. Since access to the real hardware is time consuming and limited, I am trying to simulate the errors that occur on real hardware to the best extent possible. On that note, I noticed that cross-talk and leakage errors are not included in the current implementation of Qiskit. Is there a way to do it? Or any other package you think can help simulate the cross-talk that can be used with qiskit? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that somebody from your team asked the same question. If so, please cooperate within the team and post one question only once. Here is a link to the question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32044/does-anybody-have-the-crosstalk-profile-of-the-guadalupe-system